# Access PlaceHolderText property of Textbox and set it to initially value once the Page/User Control loads

Tags: c#, user-controls, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am working on a UWP app and I have implemented a `UserControl`.The user control has multiple `Textboxes` and the usercontrol has been implemented in a different `view` page. I want to make sure that whenever the View page loads, all the textboxes have `Enter`as the default text that goes off when the textbox is highlighted.

My `UserControl` has this implementation

```
<UserControl >
 ---------------------------
----------------------------
<Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="{StaticResource brush}" BorderThickness="0,3,0,0" >
                <local:NumericTextBox x:Name="TaxifuelRevised"  IsEnabled="{Binding FuelPlanInfo.IsTappable}" Tag="TaxiFuelActual" TextAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding FuelPlanInfo.TaxiFuelActualInPreferredUnit,ElementName=rootFuelControl,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" 
                         Margin="0,0,40,0" Style="{StaticResource TransparentTextBox}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF0078D7" 
                         BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" FontSize="40" FontFamily="Helvetica" InputScope="Number" 
                         KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown" MaxLength="5" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus" Tapped="KeyBoardInputScope_Tapped"  />



            </Border>

</UserControl>
```

The `view` where it has been implemented is

```
 <Pivot x:Name="MyPivot" Grid.Row="1" ManipulationMode="None" Margin="115,10,90,20" SelectionChanged="MyPivot_SelectionChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="2536"  >

                                <PivotItem Tag="Fuel Plan" Margin="0" ManipulationMode="None">

                                <PivotItem.Header >

                                    <StackPanel >
                                        <Image Name="FuelPlanImage" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/fuel_plan_icon.png" Width="82" Height="80"></Image>
                                        <TextBlock Margin="0,8,0,0" TextAlignment="Center" Text="Fuel Plan"  FontSize="40"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </PivotItem.Header>


                                    <local:FuelPlan x:Name="FuelPlanUC" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FuelPlanInfo="{x:Bind ViewModel.FuelPlanInfo, Mode=OneWay}"></local:FuelPlan>

                            </PivotItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the PlaceholderText property of the TextBoxControl.

Comment: I know that but i need to ensure that it gets updated when the control is loaded .not happening in my case

Comment: Post the numberic textbox code. Both xaml and cs code

Comment: Ok,wait I get the issue. Its because your text is binded to an empty string.

Comment: Binding FuelPlanInfo.TaxiFuelActualInPreferredUnit,ElementName=rootFuelControl,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit could be the issue. Please post the associated property code and explicit updatesouorcetrigger